# Projected TemplateRef items removed on reorder

Tags: angular

I have a collection component that renders multiple items using a `TemplateRef` input.

When rendering multiple collection components and then reordering those collection components I've observed the `TemplateRef` items disappearing. It should also be noted that components (`TemplateRefs`) that are removed do not appear to be destroyed, i.e. the `ngOnDestroy` hook is not called for each removed component.

A full reproduction is available at https://plnkr.co/edit/GnYRzUTwwUBrdyeI9phK?p=preview

Using the `+` and `-` buttons in the reproduction, you can see that as soon as the order of the collections are changed enough to result in the UI order changing, the collections move to their appropriate positions but one the collections is now empty.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try removing animations https://plnkr.co/edit/zu1xDxZbRgsd10dhIJOA?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui That does indeed seem to resolve the issue. Does this mean I can't reliably use animations like this then? Is there a known issue related to this?

Comment: I don't know the exact related issue but seems it's a bug in angular animations

Comment: Looks like it may be related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18310. Feel free to add your comment as an answer as it solves my issue.